# find css classes that have certain styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With vanilla js, or with jquery, I want to know all the defined (available) classes that have some styling attribute defined (and what the value is).

For instance, I want to know every class that has the `border` style defined, and what it is defined to. Being able to modify that class would be great too (i.e. change the border, or delete it), but if push comes to shove, I can just query every element that uses that class and I can switch it over to a class of my choosing instead.

I'm trying to write an extension to modify the styling on a popular website. Unfortunately for me, all of the class names are meaningless and the names change frequently (they're all named "class[1..n]") So I can't use class names as a quasi intelligent way to grab certain elements, turn off their old classes and add my new custom ones. The site makes heavy use of inline styles as well and I've been able to get to most of what I need from that. However, there is a class (again, its name changes from "class12" to "class26", etc), that defines a border. I want the border to die. Right now I have to know the content within the border and go up several levels to delete the div with the border class. very annoying.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide some source that is failing? At least start reading here: http://devdocs.io/dom/document/stylesheets

Comment: Please share some code and ask for solutions.

Comment: If the targeted class always use same prefix (always `classX` where `X` is a variable), it is quite easy to filter it. Now if it changes and you have to filter by computed style instead, it is harder and doesn't really worth it. I guess, you would have better to find an other way to target these specific elements than trying to filter it by style.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('.test');
const style = getComputedStyle(elem);

// READ
console.log(style.border);

// WRITE
elem.style.border = '1px dotted green';
```

```css
.test {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">TEST</div>
```